# How do I log visited sites (for all users in a system)?

Tags: software-recommendation, logging

I want to log all sites users in my system visit. Is there any software for Ubuntu like Network Magic for Windows?

Comment: I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but the tool "wireshark" lets you monitor all network traffic - if your network isn't switched even the traffic of other computers.

Comment: thankyou, but will wireshark provide me the snapshots of the user browsing data and report of that . please help me out

Comment: Not directly. It will give you raw TCP/IP data, of which you can extract the HTML. I've been thinking. Maybe you could instead just set up a proxy server, block direct access to the internet and have the proxy server log every connection. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Logging_and_eavesdropping

Comment: Just for clarification: you want to log the traffic of users in your LAN, or users on one host - and that regarding web sites outside. Correct?

Comment: If you want to do what @guntbert says, I believe a system wide local proxy without any *"rule"* could do the job, but that's only if you want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
# apt-get install webalizer
```

> [webalizer](http://www.webalizer.org/) - A web server log file analysis tool.

[image]